# How can I set-up Postfix to handle multiple domains?

Tags: dns, postfix, mail, vps

I'm renting a VPS running Ubuntu, and I've installed the `Postfix` mail-server package on this.

I've also bought several domains.  Their DNS-entries (separate DNS-records) are all set to point to my VPS using an **A** record.  In each of the DNS-entries I've also added a **MX** record for mail; pointing to it's domain-name as specified in it's DNS-entry.

The DNS-entries pretty much all look like this (here with censored IP and fake domain-name):

```
DNS-settings for my-first-domain.com:
@     A          104.XXX.XXX.XXX          
@     MX    10   mail.my-first-domain.com.        
mail  A          104.XXX.XXX.XXX          
smtp  A          104.XXX.XXX.XXX          
www   A          104.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I've set-up each domain as a separate domain - including separate **MX**-records for mail...

- Should I've rather have used **CNAME** to make the other domains just aliases?
- Rather than separate **MX**-records; should I've rather used **CNAME**-alias, or at least let all **MX**-entries point to my "main" domain?

Assuming what I've done isn't *too* bad and can be used, how can I set-up `Postfix` to handle multiple mail-domains?  Either "separately" (preferable), or with the other domains just as aliases for the "main" domain?

I've created user-accounts for each of my domains, so for now having *all* mail to *my-first-domain.com* being delivered to the mailbox for *my-first-domain*-user would be acceptable.  (Although I suppose I may make additional mail-boxes for handling some types of mail - for example, all mail to *abuse* on any of my domains, goes to the *abuse*-mailbox.)

- So what steps must I do to set-up `Postfix` to handle mail sent to multiple domains?

I've also installed `procmail` and `mailx` - as well as the `mutt` and `alpine` mail-clients.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be looking for is virtual domains.

There are good tutorials out there regarding this topic. For instance, this one: https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-12.04-lts

Comment: My end goal is to host several web-domains...  How will virtual domains for Postfix/mail impact this?  Can using virtual domains for mail be integrated for use with web-server (Apache) too?

Comment: Web sites and Postfix virtual domains have little in common. The idea of virtual domains in Postfix is the ability to store domain information in a backend of your choice (database/LDAP/etc.) and allow a single instance of Postfix to handle multiple mail domains. Think about it as virtual hosts on Apache web server.